# Docker Compose Run on External Hard Drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker image on an external drive. Below is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  bluedrive:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/Volumes/One Touch'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - bluedrive:/essence-ruby
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: *****
      MYSQL_USER: *****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - "bluedrive:/essence-ruby/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_USER: *****
      DB_NAME: *****
      DB_PASSWORD: *****
      DB_HOST: *****
```

I ran `docker-compose run --no-deps app rails new . --force --database=mysql`

And according to [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) it's supposed to generate files like Rakefile and package.json, but I searched both the external drive and my computer's hard disk and these files are not present anywhere. But printout from the docker-compose command did show that these files were created:

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Where could these files be located? Thank you!

Comment: What type of external drive? USB? What type of filesystem, and are there any partitions? Is the external drive encrypted? It works for me using an external USB drive formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) - just that partition plus an EFI partition (on Mac, run `diskutil list` to list volumes and partitions). Do you have permissions to access the drive? Should you be mounting a directory on the volume instead of the root level of the volume?

Comment: By the way, it makes no sense to me why you'd mount the volume in the `db` container at that path. The `app` and `db` container should not need to share the same data volume. (It usually makes sense to mount a volume at `/var/lib/mysql` in a `myqsl` container, for data persistence, but no other containers should need access to the same path on the volume.)

Comment: Thanks David for trying this out and sharing the tips. I follow your tips and give it a try!